# Ckeditor '.extraPlugins' method breaks the editor

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

As stated in the title of this question, the '.extraPlugin' method is supposedly making my editor disappear. I am using ckeditor-4.5.3 (after upgrading) and it seemingly does not work. I tried using the 'wordcount' and the 'autocorrect' plugins and I traced the problem to that particular method itself.

Comment: Would anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: CKEditor does not have an `.extraPlugin` method, it does have a [`config.extraPlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins) option. Update your question with your code and build configurtaion, otherwise it's impossible to determine what is wrong with your setup.

Comment: Will do asap @AnnaTomanek. Thank you!